# Как сделать поиск по словам (по имени или по фамилии)?

Tags: c

Я даю код именно по поиску FIO

```
int search_name(teacher *arr, int size_arr, char *FIO)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[i].FIO, FIO) == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все нашел там нужно использовать strstr   // поиск подстроки в строке